# Top level element is not completed and Valid XML must have a root tag : Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am getting an error at  android:title="@string/action_refresh" and  android:title="@string/action_settings" stating Top level element is not completed and Valid XML must have a root tag. What must I do to correct this error?

**Ffragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**my.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  tools:context=".MyActivity" >
  <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">My Application</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_refresh">Refresh</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Are your two menu files in the res/menu folder?

Comment: ffragment.xml and my.xml are under the res/menu folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML validation fails with error "Top level is not completed"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445525/xml-validation-fails-with-error-top-level-is-not-completed)

Answer (score 0):

In this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445525/xml-validation-fails-with-error-top-level-is-not-completed), it is stated that you simply surround with `<root> </root>` your XML.