# Selector for button error "Valid XML document must have a root tag"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-selector

I have three image for `Button`, using png format.

I have made a `Selector` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/press_pdgmap" />

<!-- hover -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/hover_pdgmap2" />

<!-- default -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/hover_pdgmap" />

</selector>
```

But red tag appear in line pressed, hover, and default, it says

> Top level element is not completed, Valid XML document must have a root tag

note: I'm using Android Studio

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445525/xml-validation-fails-with-error-top-level-is-not-completed

Comment: You forgot to put <selector> node as parent. [Check this][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector

Comment: I'm already try this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445525/xml-validation-fails-with-error-top-level-is-not-completed) but still got red tag @codeMagic

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that to begin with. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project since making that change?

Comment: Sorry if have not mention it, because i think it's different problem, i already try to change image name, cleaning, and rebuilding project.. but stil the same @codeMagic

Comment: Ok, I've reopened then.

Comment: @Ade06: This is (now) the exact code that causes the problem? Anything else you need to add?

Comment: yes, that the exact code @njzk2

Comment: then the issue is not with the file.

Comment: then where the  issue is ?

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart (file menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top level element should be `selector` and XML file should be placed in the res/drawable/ directory.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I have moved selector to top like example, and xml file already placed in res/drawable folder, but still got red tag @Vadim

Comment: If your xml is the same as in example and placed in the right folder then everything should work. Try to run gradle `clean` task. Maybe file name or xml contains illegal characters?

Comment: @Ade06 also I have tried to copy your xml to Android Studio project (with my drawables) and it's working fine. XML in your example is valid selector.

Comment: i dont what wrong. i look into android studio everything look's fine, this my pic about the code [pic](https://imageshack.com/i/exye6aUqp) @Vadim

Comment: @Ade06 file name is `padangmap` but should be `padangmap.xml`

Comment: already do that @Vadim , but still got red tag and the problem still root tag

Comment: i have found the answer.. but i have change the selector code little bit, and have green tag in selector, this is the pic, [custom_button](https://imageshack.com/i/p8UPtt5Pp) and this my [activity](https://imageshack.com/i/p5Ecb7wPp)