# Valid XML document must have a root tag

Tags: java, xml, spring

I find stackoverflow with it, and find a post in Android, but I don't think this is fit me.

[Selector for button error "Valid XML document must have a root tag"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488183/selector-for-button-error-valid-xml-document-must-have-a-root-tag)

My snapshot is below:

[image]

And my code in `spring_datasource.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">


    <!--资源载入器 -->
    <bean
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!--数据连接池 -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource"
          init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="url" value="${connection.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${connection.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${connection.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${connection.initialSize}" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="${connection.minIdle}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="${connection.maxActive}" />

        <!-- 配置获取连接等待超时的时间 -->
        <property name="maxWait" value="60000" />
        <!-- 配置间隔多久才进行一次检测，检测需要关闭的空闲连接，单位是毫秒 -->
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000" />
        <!-- 配置一个连接在池中最小生存的时间，单位是毫秒 -->
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="300000" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false" />
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <!-- (事务管理)transaction manager, use JtaTransactionManager for global tx -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- 基于注解的事物管理 -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <!-- 当在web.xml 中DispatcherServlet使用<url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 映射时，
    能映射静态资源（当Spring Web MVC框架没有处理请求对应的控制器时（如一些静态资源），
    转交给默认的Servlet来响应静态文件，否则报404找不到资源错误，）。-->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <!-- spring和hibernate整合 -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    ${hibernate.dialect}
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                    ${hibernate.show_sql}
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">
                    ${hibernate.format_sql}
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">
                    ${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">
                    ${hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.autoReconnect">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.ldl.vision86.common.basis.entity</value>
                <value>com.ldl.vision86.business.entity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- 定时器配置
        task:executor/@pool-size：可以指定执行线程池的初始大小、最大大小
        task:executor/@queue-capacity：等待执行的任务队列的容量
        task:executor/@rejection-policy：当等待队已满时的策略，分为丢弃、由任务执行器直接运行等方式
       -->
    <task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10" />
    <task:executor id="executor" keep-alive="3600" pool-size="100-200"
                   queue-capacity="500" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
    <task:annotation-driven executor="executor" scheduler="scheduler" />
</beans>
```

I don't know where is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is no problem.

Try to Click the Create Spring facet.

[image]